# Value of hidden input returns blank when it clearly isn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I get the value from this input?  See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute on the input should be `value`, not `val`.

Answer (score 0):

Use rather :

```
$('#SortField').prop('value');
```

And in your HTML sould be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sortField" id="SortField" value="CT#" />
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/isezut/2/edit)*